# Coordinates Struct for Flow Field Pathfinding... am I doing this right?

Tags: c#, pathfinding, unity3d

I am slowly creating a flow field pathfinding solution for Unity3D.  I'm trying to follow [Elijah Emerson's description](http://www.gameaipro.com/GameAIPro/GameAIPro_Chapter23_Crowd_Pathfinding_and_Steering_Using_Flow_Field_Tiles.pdf), which appears in the book 'Game AI Pro' (volume 1).

The map is divided into sectors, and each sector houses three fields: cost, integration, flow, which need each other to calculate the flow field.

At one point I got fed up trying to reference locations in space between sectors and fields, so created a Coordinates object to handle this task.  But I'm not sure if I've created an object which makes good sense for an optimal solution?  I initially created a Struct, because the object is a data type which holds just world X and Y, along with a reference to the world this belongs to.

Because of this, I didn't want to load the object with more data fields, but I did need to reference various things described above.  So I added get-only properties which call data from elsewhere.  But is this fast and optimal?  I don't know.  I know there's an inevitable trade between memory and processing, but I just don't know what makes sense here for a fast solution.

```
using UnityEngine;

public struct Coordinates
{
    public readonly FlowFieldWorld world;
    public readonly int worldX, worldY;
    public int SectorX { get { return worldX % world.SectorSize; } }
    public int SectorY { get { return worldY % world.SectorSize; } }
    public FlowFieldSector Sector { get { return world.Sectors[worldX / world.SectorSize, worldY / world.SectorSize]; } }
    public CostTile Cost { get { return Sector.CostField[SectorX, SectorY]; } }
    public IntegrationTile Integration { get { return Sector.IntegrationField[SectorX, SectorY]; } }
    public FlowTile Flow { get { return Sector.FlowField[SectorX, SectorY]; } }
    public bool IsWalkable { get { return Cost.Value != 255; } }
    public readonly static Coordinates zero = new Coordinates(0, 0, null);
    public Vector3 Vector3 { get { return new Vector3(worldX, 0, worldY); } }

    public Coordinates(int worldX, int worldY, FlowFieldWorld world)
    {
        this.worldX = worldX;
        this.worldY = worldY;
        this.world = world;
    }

    public Coordinates(Coordinates coordinates)
    {
        this.worldX = coordinates.worldX;
        this.worldY = coordinates.worldY;
        this.world = coordinates.world;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Coordinates left, Coordinates right)
    {
        return left.worldX == right.worldX && left.worldY == right.worldY;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Coordinates left, Coordinates right)
    {
        return left.worldX != right.worldX || left.worldY != right.worldY;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Coordinates coordinates && Equals(coordinates);
    }

    public bool Equals(Coordinates other)
    {
        return worldX == other.worldX && worldY == other.worldY;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 1845962855;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + worldX.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + worldY.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no knowledge about Unity3d, so here are some general comments.

If `world.SectorSize` is constant throughout the session, you can change some of the properties to readonly fields and calculate them in the constructor:

```
public readonly int SectorX;
public readonly int SectorY;
public readonly FlowFieldSector Sector;
...


public Coordinates(int worldX, int worldY, FlowFieldWorld world)
{
  this.worldX = worldX;
  this.worldY = worldY;
  this.world = world;
  SectorX = worldX % world.SectorSize;
  SectorY = worldY % world.SectorSize;
  Sector =  world.Sectors[worldX / world.SectorSize, worldY / world.SectorSize];
}
```

Doing so with `Sector`, `Cost`, `Integration` and `Flow` requires of cause that these objects are reference types and not replaced - if they are updated while the `Coordinates` instance lives. It is probably just a micro optimization - but everything counts?

---

> ```
> public bool Equals(Coordinates other)
> {
>   return worldX == other.worldX && worldY == other.worldY;
> }
> ```

This is actually an implementation of `IEquatable<Coordinates>` so you can add this interface to the inheritance list:

```
public struct Coordinates : IEquatable<Coordinates>
```

---

In respect to the DRY-principle you could do the following changes:

The copy constructor can call the other constructor:

```
public Coordinates(Coordinates source) : this(source.worldX, source.worldY, source.world)
{
}
```

The comparison operators can call `Equals(Coordinates other)`:

```
public static bool operator ==(Coordinates left, Coordinates right)
{
  return left.Equals(right);
}
```